# Get street suggestion (start point) in GMaps Directions service

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, driving-directions

I'm using Google Maps API 3 for returning directions from user's input address (destination node) to a Store (predefined start node).

I ask for user's address (not geolocation but through a simple input field) but I wouldn't like the user to narrow their input by entering extra info like postcode, state, city. I just want to make the input of the user as little as possible, e.g. 123 Road street.

However, when I type an address with a common name (like 25 Main street), the route I get is possibly the first result that Google has available, even if it is 3000 miles away when the user's address could be 2 miles away.

I have read all Google's documentation in regards to Directions service but I couldn't find anything that relates to street suggestions. Do you know how I can serve suggestions to the user so that the start address would be the exact match of user's preference?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this is impossible to achieve without any detail for the  real location of the user.

Of course you would be able to filter results(regardless of the used service) by the distance, but how could you know if the user is located at the nearest address...you can't.

A possible solution may be to use a [places-autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete) (i guess that's what you mean by *"serve suggestions"*), the user would be able to choose his location from the predictions.

Another approach:
Instead of a input-field you may let the user click on the map to mark his location

Comment: I ended up using `places-autocomplete` but my intention was to retrieve a list of suggestions after the user hits "enter". I didn't like the idea of autocomplete (the way Google implements it) because the user loses focus from typing. With `places-autocomplete` you can set the bound area of suggestions, which is very useful, but then again I needed a list of suggestions after user's input. Any ideas on this?

Comment: Use a [**radarSearch**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#radar_search_requests)

Comment: radarSearch returns results from "Places within a specified search radius". I needed to return address suggestions, just like the "places-autocomplete" does but in a list after user's input.

Comment: It returns results within a radius **or bounds**. The list you'll have to create on your own based on the response.

Comment: The autocomplete-results may also be fetched via service: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#place_autocomplete_service

Comment: Perfect! that's all I needed! Please update your answer so that I accept it. Thank you